# Android NDK shared library compilation problems cannot compile static library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm having some problems with compiling .cpp file with NDK. It seems not to be finding static library libIrmaMatrix. Any suggestions?

Here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#IrmaMatrixLib
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := irmaMatrix 
$(warning $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a
LOCAL_LDLIBS   = -lz -lm -lc
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

##BoostSystem
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libSystem
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := boost/lib/libboost_system-gcc-mt-1_55.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

#libAtomic
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libAtomic
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := boost/lib/libboost_atomic-gcc-mt-1_55.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

#libChrono
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libChrono
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := boost/lib/libboost_chrono-gcc-mt-1_55.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

#libProgramOptions
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libProgramOptions 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := boost/lib/libboost_program_options-gcc-mt-1_55.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

#libThread
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libThread
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := boost/lib/libboost_thread-gcc-mt-1_55.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/include/boost-1_55
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/include/boost-1_55
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/include/iris/sensor-api
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/prebuild/static/libIrmaMatrix.a
LOCAL_MODULE    := AVL
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME:= libAVL
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := AVL.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := irmaMatrix 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libSystem 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libAtomic 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libThread 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libChrono 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libProgramOptions 
LOCAL_LDLIBS   := -lz -lm -lc

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a-hard
#APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_MODULES := AVL
APP_PLATFORM := android-18
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
```

Following errors:

```
[armeabi-v7a-hard] SharedLibrary  : libAVL.so
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(Connection.o): in function iris::drivers::Connection::~Connection():Connection.cpp(.text+0x39c): error: undefined reference to '__assert_fail'
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(Connection.o): in function iris::drivers::Connection::~Connection():Connection.cpp(.text+0x4a8): error: undefined reference to '__assert_fail'
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(Connection.o): in function iris::drivers::Connection::~Connection():Connection.cpp(.text+0x5b4): error: undefined reference to '__assert_fail'
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(Connection.o): in function iris::drivers::Connection::unregisterSensor(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&):Connection.cpp(.text+0x77c): error: undefined reference to '__assert_fail'
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(LogFile.o): in function iris::utilities::LogFile::readEntryAt(long long):LogFile.cpp(.text+0x208): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::seekg(std::fpos<__mbstate_t>)'
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(DriverManager.o): in function iris::drivers::DriverManager::loadDrivers(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool):DriverManager.cpp(.text+0x1d8c): error: undefined reference to 'boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(DriverManager.o): in function iris::drivers::DriverManager::loadDrivers(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool):DriverManager.cpp(.text+0x1dec): error: undefined reference to 'boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_increment(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(DriverManager.o): in function void boost::checked_delete<boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp>(boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp*):DriverManager.cpp(.text._ZN5boost14checked_deleteINS_10filesystem6detail11dir_itr_impEEEvPT_+0x1c): error: undefined reference to 'boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&, void*&)'
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(DriverManager.o): in function boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp>::dispose():DriverManager.cpp(.text._ZN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pINS_10filesystem6detail11dir_itr_impEE7disposeEv+0x20): error: undefined reference to 'boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&, void*&)'
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(DriverManager.o): in function boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(boost::filesystem::path const&):DriverManager.cpp(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem18directory_iteratorC1ERKNS0_4pathE+0xb8): error: undefined reference to 'boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(DriverManager.o): in function boost::filesystem::detail::recur_dir_itr_imp::increment(boost::system::error_code*):DriverManager.cpp(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem6detail17recur_dir_itr_imp9incrementEPNS_6system10error_codeE+0x58): error: undefined reference to 'boost::filesystem::directory_entry::m_get_symlink_status(boost::system::error_code*) const'
............
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(utf8wchar.o): in function gcc_coding_to_coding(char const*, char const*, char const*, unsigned int, char*, unsigned int):utf8wchar.cpp(.text+0xd8): error: undefined reference to 'iconv'
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/iris/sensor-api/static/libIrmaMatrix.a(utf8wchar.o): in function gcc_coding_to_coding(char const*, char const*, char const*, unsigned int, char*, unsigned int):utf8wchar.cpp(.text+0xe8): error: undefined reference to 'iconv_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a-hard/libAVL.so] Error 1
```

I'm using hard cause of error I get when I'm using only armeabi-v7a: *uses VFP register arguments, output does not*

Answer (score 0):

Seems like linker is not able to find definitions of standard c++ library functions and also functions in boost library. Please check have to set library paths for `boost` and `libIraMatrix`correctly in Makefile,

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := irmaMatrix 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libSystem 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libAtomic 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libThread 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libChrono 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libProgramOptions
```

Probably, You can do do something like below,

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/path/to/the/library
```

Use above settings for `boost` libraries and `libIraMatrix`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I made it up to 1 error: 

/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a-hard/objs/AVL/AVL.o: in function device_scan:jni/AVL.cpp:255: error: undefined reference to 'iris::drivers::DriverManager::getInstance()'
 | 
static jint device_scan(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jint asdf) {
 DriverManager& dm = DriverManager::getInstance();
    return 0;
}
 | 
Seems like object is not found but it should be as the .a lib is compiled...

Comment: Looks like definition of static method `iris::drivers::DriverManager::getInstance()` is not found. Please check where this function is implemented and properly include its .cpp file during compilation.

Comment: The problem is that I have only header files of the classes and static library with the source (libIrmaMatrix.a) but not the .cpp files and I'm confused what to do..

Comment: Please check one more thing that have you spelled libIraMatrix in line `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := irmaMatrix ` correctly? Please check once. You don't need source files but you need library to link correctly because it has actual implementation of functions in it.

Comment: Yes it is `irmaMatrix` no `iraMatrix` found.